# How to update a sub-collection document when sub sub-collection is created in firestore using cloud functions typescript

Tags: typescript, flutter, google-cloud-functions

i have this functions that aimed to update the commentsCount field of a comment when sub comment is created but its not working which i dont know why. im hitting the correct document id to be updated but i dont know why its not updating. it doesn't have any error though. the console is running normally and says :
`i  functions: Beginning execution of "onCreateSubComment"

> 1d0HczjEvZM0T4u9iXb0
> 1d0HczjEvZM0T4u9iXb0
> i  functions: Finished "onCreateSubComment" in ~1s`

```html
//example code on how to update a document when sub collection is created in firestore.

export const onCreateComment = functions.firestore
    .document("posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context)=> {
      const postRefId = context.params.postId;
      const snapRef = snap.ref;
      const commentCollectionRef = snapRef.parent;
      const postRef = commentCollectionRef.parent;
      const postId = postRef?.id;
      try {
        return await db.collection("posts").doc(postId ?? postRefId)
            .update({commentsCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
      } catch (e) {
        functions.logger.log(e);
        throw e;
      }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzk0W.png)

```html
//example code on how to update sub collection when sub sub collection is created in firestore.

export const onCreateSubComment = functions.firestore
    .document("posts/{postId}/comments/{commentId}/subComments/{subCommentId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const commentRefId = context.params.commentId;
      const postId = context.params.postId;
      const snapRef = snap.ref;
      const subCommentCollectionRef = snapRef.parent;
      const commentRef = subCommentCollectionRef.parent;
      const commentId =commentRef?.id;
      console.log(commentId);
      console.log(commentRefId);
      try {
        return await db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments")
            .doc(commentId ?? commentRefId )
            .update({commentsCount: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
      } catch (e) {
        functions.logger.log(e);
        throw e;
      }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvt69.png)g

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LuWa.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Comment: it doesnt have any error at all in the console. it is just not working. it is not updating what it needs to update. I have a similar implementation in updating the post's commentsCount when a comment is created and its working perfectly fine..but i dont know why it doesnt work on the subComments collection.

Comment: @toyotaSupra is the code not visible? im sorry its my first time to post here. i added the code to the snippet box but i dont know if it is visible to others.

Comment: Try restarting the functions and firestore emulators.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the field name between quotation marks, so instead of `commentsCount` use `"commentsCount"`, like:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments")
  .doc(commentId ?? commentRefId )
  .update({"commentsCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)});
```

Besides, I would rather use `set` with option `merge: true` instead of `update`. This way the other fields won'be affected. Like this:

```
db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments")
  .doc(commentId ?? commentRefId )
  .set({"commentsCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  }, {merge: true});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i tried it and its not working either...

        return await db.collection("posts").doc(postId).collection("comments")
            .doc(commentId ?? commentRefId )
            .set({"commentsCount": admin.firestore.FieldValue
                .increment(1)}, {merge: true});

Comment: If you pause in the debugger on this line do you see all values as right?

Comment: i solved it..the code is correct, it is just conflicting with my onDelete function because when i copy pasted to create onDelete function, i forgot to edit the .onCreate  to .onDelete thats why everytime i create  a sub comment, it is updating but my onDelete is also decrementing it thats why it looks like nothing is happening.. thanks anyway. if not because of your last comment i didnt figure this out.

Comment: Good to hear, happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

i solved it. nothing is wrong with the code. it is just conflicting my other functions. thanks to those who have given their time to help. y'all are awesome.